# Why should I use fork() for making simple shell in C

Tags: c, shell

I don't know why I need to use the `fork()` function.

I already make many functions like `cat`, `cd`, `mkdir`, `ps`, `ls` ...
But, when I saw other's code, many people use `fork()` function.
I know what it is and how to work is. But I don't understand why this function is needed to make simple shell.
I want to know how to use this function to make simple shell.

Comment: A shell parses a string and creates children to execute the commands in that string.  You use "fork' to create children.  It is the basic building block of a shell.

Comment: Depends on how you design your "simple shell". I'm sure it's not thrown there unnecessarily.

Comment: One characteristic of `fork()` is that, because it creates a new, isolated process, any modifications you make to it and it's environment doesn't necessarily affect the parent process, so it gives you freedom to thinker with setuid, modify environment variables etc. without rendering the shell broken once the command you ran is done.

Comment: Does your shell support `ls -lhrt` to show files with details and human readable sizes sorted by modification time ascending? Other people's shells do because they use `fork+exec` to start the system `ls` program instead of writing their own. Does your shell support `ls | grep txt | wc -l` to get the number of text files in the directory? Other people's shells do because they use `fork()` to create pipelines.

Comment: The BusyBox shell uses a lot of built-in functions to emulate system commands (like your `ps`, `ls`, `mkdir`, `cat`).  But I believe even that uses `fork()` when it comes to managing a pipeline — two or more processes connected by pipes.

Answer (score 0):

This is a design.

People are not using fork(), but fork()-exec() pattern to make a new process. It sounds to me that you make your shell understand cat, cd, etc. and I have an impression that you created not a shell, but a REPL program. That is fine. Bash, for example, also have some commands working in this way (such as, functions you defined, "bg", etc.) but you limited the functionality to your shell to only the stuff you implemented.

A fork-exec, however, is to allow your shell to run a program. And more importantly, the program being run will not mess with your shell. For example, no segmentation fault on the program can stop your shell from running. In my opinion, this part is the more important aspect of a shell.